# How can I use Script to set the backgrounds of a range of cells to specific Hex codes stored elsewhere in a Google Sheets doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Complete rework of my question. Sorry, I am apparently not very good at explaining. New sheet, [Question Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WGXtfHgp7mJhDD3w35NvU-ENgxjkE-hdJXbYlL3s62I/edit?usp=sharing). Just has the bit I am asking about, with a couple of lines explaining the question.

I have a sheet on which you input various traits of two dragons, using the system from a web game called Flight Rising. The basic genes are working fine. The colors are my issue. I want to be able to see the portion of the color wheel that will be available for offspring visually.

I have already made functions to pull the relevant colors and place the hex codes into a range on the Data sheet, one row per color slot, Z2:DI4. I want to pull one row's worth of values for each color slot and use it to define the background colors of a range on the Working sheet. Columns K through CT, row 4 for primary color pulling from row 2 on the Data sheet, row 6 for secondary color pulling from row 3 on the Data sheet, and row 8 for tertiary color pulling from row 4 on the Data sheet. I have outlined the relevant areas on the sheet in neon green to hopefully make that mess of a description more clear.

I want the hex codes on the "Data" sheet to become the background colors on the "Working" sheet.

Edit 2: Here is my full sheet, with a bit of modification from before to try to make it easier to understand my explanation. I need the same function as the Demo sheet, but the source of hex numbers is the named range "ColorHex1", and the cells to change color are the named range "ColorRange1". They are on different sheets in the workbook. [Gene Comparison Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U2SeDTETdTDScQgjjiRxVY7FgZDAeIH8hO0yFNL4rD4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think it would be great if you could share a testing sheet for us to be able to get a better understanding of the issue and how you are managing the data so we can try to help you find a solution.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your interest. Sorry I didn't describe it very well. I added a link, and I am adding screenshots explaining what goes where now.

Comment: @FernandoLara Likewise, thank you for your interest, I hope the added info is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the sample input and output situations you expect.

Comment: @Quinn Tanaike is right. I think this is achievable but could you provide an example of how you define the color logic to understand what will be the input data and have a couple sample expected results to have a full understanding of multiple scenarios?

Comment: @Tanaike, Is this better?

Comment: @FernandoLara Is this example sheet more useful?

Comment: @Tanaike May I ask what your native language is? I might be able to restructure the question more effectively if I know.

Comment: I added a sentence and some arrows to the sheet itself to indicate which cell has the color (as a hex code) and which one should be that color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish exactly what you mentioned in the testing sheet you first need to read the ranges where the Hex codes are, then get the values from the ranges and read the range where you are trying to show the colors and use `setBackground()` and send the hex code value as a parameter of the function.

#### Sample code:

```js
function cellColorChange() {
  
  //Declaring sheets
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Working");

  // Obtaining hex codes from the ranges
  var sourcePrimary = sourceSheet.getRange("AA2:DJ2").getValues().flat();
  var sourceSecondary = sourceSheet.getRange("AA3:DJ3").getValues().flat();
  var sourceTertiary = sourceSheet.getRange("AA4:DJ4").getValues().flat();

  //Setting colors for "Primary" row 
  for(var i=0; i<sourcePrimary.length; i++)
  {
    targetSheet.getRange(4, i+12).setBackground(sourcePrimary[i]);
  }

  //Setting colors for "Secondary" row 
  for(var j=0; j<sourceSecondary.length; j++)
  {
    targetSheet.getRange(5, j+12).setBackground(sourceSecondary[j]);
  }

  //Setting colors for "Tertiary" row 
  for(var k=0; k<sourceTertiary.length; k++)
  {
    targetSheet.getRange(6, k+12).setBackground(sourceTertiary[k]);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Ah, good, I am glad the question makes sense now! I am sorry I was so bad at explaining. I have added my actual sheet to the end of the question; your example relies on the source and output being on the same tab, which they aren't in my sheet. I apologize if I made it more confusing in the process of trying to simplify. Does the second edit make sense?

Comment: @Quinn edited my answer with the new code. Let me know if that works better now!

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much for sticking with me!